# Recursive Merge Sort C++

Tags: visual-c++

I want to write a recursive merge sort program in C++. The problem is, I don't know how to get the base case idea working recursively. Can anybody please tell me what would be the base case for `Merg Function()`, `Split Function()` and `MergSort()` function. I would be thankful to you.

```
void Merg(int A[], int s1, int e1, int s2, int e2)
{
   int B[8];
   int i=0;

   while (A[s1] < A[s2])
      B[i] = B[s1];
      i++;
      s1++;

      if (s1 == e1)
      {
         B[i] = A[s2];
         i++;
         s2++;
      }

   while (A[s2] < A[s1])
      B[i] = B[s2];
      i++;
      s2++;

      if (s2 == e2)
      {
         B[i] = A[s1];
         i++;
         s1++;
      }
}

void Split(int A[], int s, int e)
{
   int mid = (s+e)/2;

   if (s < e && mid != 0)
   {   
      Split(A, s, mid);
      Split(A, mid+1, e);   
   }
   Merg(A, s, mid, mid+1, e);
}

int main()
{
   int A[8] = {10,4,8,12,11,2,7,5};

   Split(A, 0, 7);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's pseudo-code [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort).

Answer (score 1):

The base case is an array that is guaranteed to be sorted, so either an empty array or an array of length 1.

Your merge function is not correct, but at least contains most of the right ideas. All you need there is a further wrapping loop and a few conditions to prevent your merge running past the end of the arrays. The split function is totally off, splitting is not recursive, further splits happen inside the recursive `mergeSort` calls.

1. if length(A) < 2 return // already sorted
2. split A in lower half L and upper half H
3. merge-sort L
4. merge-sort H
5. merge the sorted L and H
6. done